# Elasticsearch 5.1 Bulk Action

Tags: java, php, elasticsearch, elastica

I'm try to make a bulk update

> Method: Post
>   Url: /customer/external/_bulk

Json Body:

```
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"name": "John Doe" }
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"name": "Jane Doe" }
```

Id 1 is updated but id 2 didnt update. I dont know why?

Response is here:

```
{
  "took": 138,
  "errors": false,
  "items": [
    {
      "index": {
        "_index": "customer",
        "_type": "external",
        "_id": "1",
        "_version": 15,
        "result": "updated",
        "_shards": {
          "total": 2,
          "successful": 1,
          "failed": 0
        },
        "created": false,
        "status": 200
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure to add a new line after the fourth line??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Val mentioned, you should be having the new line character `\n` at the end of the last line in your `json` body:

```
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"name": "John Doe" }
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"name": "Jane Doe" }\n
```

as per mentioned in [bulk_api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#docs-bulk). Hope it helps!